# android custom application icon

Tags: android

is it possible to make large/custom size icon on the desktop for android?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they expect a 48 by 48 pixel icon: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Comment: but the clock application that comes with android seems to have a very large icon than the rest

Comment: What "clock application"? If you mean the analog clock on the home screen, that is an app widget, not an application icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Android Icon Generating Tool  :  [Android Asset Studio](http://jennifer-androidworld.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-asset-studio-android-icon.html)